# Sed: unmatched '/'

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Есть такая команда `sed '/[K>/d' log.txt`. Почему я получаю ошибку `unmatched '/'`?

Comment: Какой шелл используете?

Comment: @tutankhamun такую ошибку выдал sh. bash выдал `sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated address regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях sed есть служебные символы

```
$.*/[\]^
```

Если они используются как символы, их нужно экранировать. В вашем случае

```
sed '/\[K>/d' log.txt
```

Посмотрите ответ на подобный вопрос здесь
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Comment: спасибо, работает. Нужно ещё использовать аргумент -i.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо потому, что первый слеш считается открывающим регэксп, а второй вместе с `d` указывает на десятичную цифру. В итоге регэксп не закрыт.

**UPD**
Ерунду написал. Нужно экранировать `[` иначе второй слеш считается как один из символьного класса и соответственно не находится закрывающий слеш